# Application of calculus in kinematics

Tags: calculus, physics, kinematics

A body is bound to move along a straight line, say X-axis.It is initially   at rest at origin.It moves to point (1m,0) in one second and comes to rest. How can we prove that absolute value of acceleration of this particle exceeds 4ms*2 atleast once?

Comment: Do you mean it accelerates then decelerates and stops at 1?

Comment: This might be more suited to [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com), but make sure to read through their [guides](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help) to make sure your question is well-received.

Comment: Your acceleration limit is lacking a unit.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

- Consider a scenario in which the body moves as quickly as possible given the acceleration threshold.
- Does the body reach its goal within the given time?
- Can any body with less acceleration be faster?